# Array to Set conversion taking 20 seconds - Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, set

Why is this conversion from array of strings to a Set taking so long?

I am reading data from Core Data and converting the fetched results into an array of Strings and then from the array to a set.  The conversion from the array to set is taking around 20 seconds in the simulator.

If there is no data in Core Data, I read a text file into a string array and then convert the array to a set.  Doing the conversion here takes less than 1 second.

The data in Core Data is the same as the text file as I am saving the loaded text file into Core Data. So the two string arrays I'm converting should be identical?

Any help?

Function that converts array to set in ~20 second

```
func coreData() {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate // UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate is now UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Sowpods")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request) as? [NSManagedObject] ?? []
        if results.count > 0 {
            print("Results fetched")

            // Load words from Core Data into wordSet
            let wordsArray = results.flatMap { $0.value(forKey: "words") as? String }

            let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
            print("Putting fetched results from Array into Set")
            print("Words in array: \(wordsArray.count)")

            wordSet = Set(wordsArray.map { $0 }) /////// ~20 Seconds ///////////

            let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
            print("Time to put fetched results into wordSet: \(timeElapsed) s")

        } else {
            print("No results fetched from Core Data")
            // Read Dictionary

            wordSet = self.readDictionary(dictionaryFileName: "sowpods", dictionaryFileExtension: "txt")

            // Load words in dictionary into Core Data
            for word in wordSet {
                let newWord = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Sowpods", into: context)
                newWord.setValue(word, forKey: "words")
            }
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print("Failed to save words")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Couldn't fetch results")
    }
}
```

Function that converts array to set in < 1 second

```
func readDictionary(dictionaryFileName: String, dictionaryFileExtension: String) -> Set<String> {
    print("Loading Dictionary")
    var wordsArray: [String] = []
    do {
        // This solution assumes  you've got the file in your bundle
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: dictionaryFileName, ofType: dictionaryFileExtension){
            let data = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            wordsArray = data.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
        }
    } catch let err as NSError {
        // do something with Error
        print(err)
    }

    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    //print("Loading Dictionary")
    print("Words in array: \(wordsArray.count)")

    let dictionarySet = Set(wordsArray.map { $0 }) /////// < 1 Seconds ///////////

    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print("Time to load dictionary Array into Set: \(timeElapsed) s")


    print("Done Loading Dictionary")
    return dictionarySet
}
```

**Log from quick conversion**

- No results fetched from Core Data
- Loading Dictionary
- Words in array: 267627
- Time to load dictionary Array into Set: 0.7359259724617 s
- Done Loading Dictionary

**Log from slow conversion**

- Results fetched
- Putting fetched results from Array into Set
- Words in array: 267627
- Time to put fetched results into wordSet: 18.0488159656525 s

Comment: how about Set(wordsArray) ?

Comment: Use returns​Distinct​Results for the coreData

Comment: @Lu_ No, same time using `wordSet = Set(wordsArray)`

Comment: what is the size of the arrays in the both cases ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to convert your core data objects into a Set?

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Adding `request.returnsDistinctResults = true` didn't change time. Both count = 267627.  See logs posted.

Comment: @AshleyMills Hmm, I'm checking user entered words against the words in the Set which is quicker than checking against an array.  But I could possibly just check against the Core Data directly using `request.predicate`?  Still that doesn't explain the time differences between the two seemingly identical conversions.

Comment: Yeah - you _really_ don't want to do that. If you're looking to see if a word exists, just write an `NSFetchRequest` and get a count for it. Sounds like another question!

Comment: Why are you applying the `.map{$0}` here? That shouldn't be necessary for converting an Array to a Set. It's forcing you to make a copy of the array, however. Also, while possibly minor, you are assigning directly to a property in one case and to a local variable in the other. If `wordSet` includes a `didSet`, that would be an obvious difference.

Comment: @RobNapier Not sure, just a newbie copy paste :)  Changing to `wordSet = Set(wordsArray)` made no real improvement. Changing both to a local variable also made no change.

Comment: @AshleyMills I've been trying to check user entered words against the Core Data using `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "words = %@", word.lowercased())`.  It works without any noticeable delay.  BUT, my code is also 'solving' the puzzle which uses a recursive function which is continually checking for correct words.  Checking for valid words here with repeated fetch requests takes the time to solve boards from seconds to minutes.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that the strings you obtain from the database have trailing spaces ?

This could make them much longer than the ones in the text file causing the Set's hashing algorithm to work harder and possibly getting into collisions.

I measured a 3x time increase by adding 40 spaces to a wordlist of 238k words when converting to a Set.  With more spaces and/or different words, this could explain part if not all of the 20x difference you're getting.

Or, perhaps, the dictionary values with the key "words" contains more than one word per record (as its name suggests) which would also make for larger strings in the array, and possibly fewer duplicates in the set.

You should compare the number of elements in the file's dictionarySet with the database's wordSet.  I suspect that you could have a lot fewer entries in the file based set for some reason (which could also explain the time difference).

Comment: Thanks, there must have been some slight difference between the two arrays, although both has no duplicates or trailing spaces. I change the code that created the core data `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject` to iterate through the array rather than the set.  Then when I read the Core Data back on the next run it converts in < 1 second. Not sure why this fixes it.